# react-native-twilio-video-webrtc Android compilation error

Tags: javascript, android, twilio, react-native

I'm using [this module](https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc) to implement Twilio Video services on my app. When configuring it on Android, I follow the steps given in the documentation and I get this error on buid (using react-native run-android).

```
node_modules/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc/android/src/main/java/com/twiliorn/library/TwilioPackage.java:27:
error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

    @Override
    ^

    Note: node_modules/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc/android/src/main/java/com/twiliorn/library/CustomTwilioVideoView.java uses or overrides a deprecated API


1 error :react-native-twilio-video-webrtc:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

It's kinda blocking me from doing what I have to. If you have any solution, I would love it

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks as though the React Native project [removed `createJSModules` in version 0.47.0](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.47.0) which is being overridden in the [React Native Twilio Video project](https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/twiliorn/library/TwilioPackage.java#L27).

This has been [reported to the project maintainers and is being worked on](https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc/issues/34). I'd keep an eye on the project to see when they release an update.

Comment: Yes I'm the one who reported it to the maintainers (ShadeIsaac), we're working on it right now, thanks for the update !

Comment: Ahh! Your usernames didn't seem connected to me, so I wrote up the answer. Hope it's sorted soon.

Comment: Yes I change my username here but my GitHub one is still my old one. Yes I hope it's sorted soon too !
Note : expect me to contact you soon since I intend to work with Twilio a lot on this project ! ;)

Comment: I'm excited to hear what you're building!